# For the group action of $G=S_3$ on $A=S_3$, $g\cdot a=ga$, find the image of $(1\;2\;3)$ under the permutation representation $S_3\to S_A\cong S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, permutations, symmetric-groups

> For the group action of $G=S_3$ on $A=S_3$, written $g\cdot a=ga$, find the image of $(1\;2\;3)$ under the permutation representation $S_3\to S_A\cong S_6$.

**Here's the given solution to the problem**: Recall that the permutation representation of the group action is given by the map $$\Sigma: G\to S_A$$ $$g\mapsto \sigma_g, \sigma_g(a) = ga,$$ where $g\in G, a\in A$. Note that $A = \{(1), (1\;2),(1\;3), (2\;3), (1\;2\;3), (1\;3\;2)\}$. So, $$\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}\hline a & \sigma_{(1\;2\;3)} & \sigma_g(a) = ga\\ \hline(1) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(1) = (1\;2\;3) \\ \hline  (1\;2) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(1\;2) = (1\;3) \\ \hline  (1\;3) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(1\;3) = (2\;3) \\ \hline   (2\;3) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(2\;3) = (1\;2) \\ \hline  (1\;2\;3) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(1\;2\;3) = (1\;3\;2) \\ \hline  (1\;3\;2) & \overset{\sigma_{(1\;2\;3)}}\mapsto & (1\;2\;3)(1\;3\;2) = (1). \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Observe that if we enumerate $A$ like so: $$A = \{\overset{\bf 1}{(1)}, \overset{\bf 2}{(1\;2)}, \overset{\bf 3}{(1\;3)}, \overset{\bf 4}{(2\;3)}, \overset{\bf 5}{(1\;2\;3)}, \overset{\bf 6}{(1\;3\;2)}\},$$ then the image of $(1\;2\;3)$ under the permutation representation $S_3\to S_A\cong S_6$ is determined by the following:

Starting at ${\bf 1}$ and consulting the mappings in the above table, we get $$({\bf1} \; {\bf5} \; {\bf6})({\bf2} \; {\bf3} \; {\bf4}).$$

**Here's my question**: Is this answer *unique* exactly? The problem statement says to find **the** image of $(1\;2\;3)$, but I'm slightly confused on the enumeration part. What stops anybody from just choosing the enumeration of $A$ to be $$A = \{\overset{\bf 1}{(1)}, \overset{\bf 2}{(1\;2)}, \overset{\bf 3}{(1\;3)}, \overset{\bf 5}{(2\;3)}, \overset{\bf 6}{(1\;2\;3)}, \overset{\bf 4}{(1\;3\;2)}\}?$$ In other words, perhaps I didn't think of the elements of $S_3$ in some kind of order. Because then we get the image to be $$({\bf 1\;6\;4})({\bf 2 \;5\;6}).$$

Am I missing something here? Apparently $S_A \cong S_6$, which means that the elements should map to "something" that have the same order (if I'm not mistaken), because then we wouldn't have an isomorphism. But how exactly do we *know* this ordering doesn't work beforehand? Can someone explain what my logical fallacy might be here?

Comment: If you didn't re-label $A$ then you'd get $$( (1),(123),(132))((12),(13),(23)).$$ For each way of labelling $A$ with the labels $1,2,3,4,5,6$ you get a different isomorphism between $S_A$ and $S_{\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}}=S_6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you regard the Cayley map $S_3\to S(S_3)$, then
$$(1\,2\,3\,)\mapsto((1)\,(1\,2\,3\,)\,(3\,2\,1))((1\,2)\,(1\,3)\,(2\,3))$$
as note in the comments. This would be **the** image of $(1\,2\,3)$ under the natural map.

As you observe, if you compose with an isomorphism $S(S_3)\to S_6$, uniqueness is only up to how you label elements of $S_3$ (and the only mistake you are making is thinking that there is some labelling that doesn't work). I personally like the labelling
$$
\{\overset{\bf 1}{(1)}, \overset{\bf 2}{(1\;2\;3)}, \overset{\bf 3}{(3\;2\;1)}, \overset{\bf 4}{(1\;2)}, \overset{\bf 5}{(1\;3)}, \overset{\bf 6}{(2\;3)}\}
$$
so that $(1\,2\,3\,)\mapsto(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)$.

In general, this is the only freedom you have, but the case of $S_6$ is actually very special. For $S_6$, there is an exotic isomorphism $S_6\to S_6$ determined by the mapping
\begin{align}
(1\;2)&\mapsto(1\;2)(3\;4)(5\;6)\\
(2\;3)&\mapsto(1\;4)(2\;5)(3\;6)\\
(3\;4)&\mapsto(1\;3)(2\;4)(5\;6)\\
(4\;5)&\mapsto(1\;2)(3\;6)(4\;5)\\
(5\;6)&\mapsto(1\;4)(2\;3)(5\;6)
\end{align}
The composition $S_3\to S(S_3)\cong S_6\to S_6$ using my labelling above yields
$$(1\;2\;3)\mapsto(2\;4\;6).$$